# Error while running the published website on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

I have an asp.net website which is developed in asp.net 4.0 with data binding from a database which is maintain in sql server 2000..
It it working fine on localhost but when I am deploying it on IIS and while running the page following error is occurring.

`Login failed for user 'testuser'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.`

`Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code`.

`Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Login failed for user 'testuser'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.`

Source Error:

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

- I am using mixed mode authentication and sql server 2008 is installed
  on my system
- I am using the following connection string in my .cs
  page

`using (OleDbConnection con3 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sbs;User ID=testuser;Passwrd=pinkCITY01;Initial Catalog=PCGnet"))`

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere else, the `sa` user is not used in the connection string you provided.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615 and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/a1a371f8-7ed2-47f8-b155-a553d47fb6e9/

Comment: check to see if your sa user is enabled and able to connect to the database in your connection string

Comment: @alex..actuly its "testuser" not 'sa' ..typo error...any help now ?

Comment: anything to do with the compatibility(version) issue ??

Comment: @Rajeev make sure "testuser" has full access to the "sbs" database you are referencing in your connection string

Comment: @davidb..yup I had provided all the rights and roles to 'testuser' for 'sbs'

Answer (score 0):

try adding **Integrated Security=SSPI** to connection string

or refer below link

[Login Failed 'sa'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/a1a371f8-7ed2-47f8-b155-a553d47fb6e9/)

Comment: I used Integrated Security=SSPI..but no love..now it showing..Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection